# Is there any other alternative to PHP which allows me to deploy unreadable code on a server?

Tags: php, security, content-management-system, webserver, bytecode

I am developing a CMS which has a PHP Encryption engine. But as the PHP code is completely visible, the method of encryption of data is easily compromised as every person who purchases the product can read the code. I want to pre compile the PHP or use any other server side scripting language that allows me to give a file containing the byte code of the program and which carries out the exact same function as the original PHP file. Is there any such language?

Comment: Zend Guard is an option, but that requires a module installed on the customer's server, which may not be something they would be willing to do.

Comment: Do you want to make it *difficult* or *impossible* to read the code?  The first is trivial- change to a compiled language. The latter is not really possible if the code resides on machines outside of your control.

Comment: Any precompiled code can probably be decompiled, so in this case code obfuscation may be the best answer. I feel like I have seen a similar question before, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Spending time writing a bulletproof EULA will pay off far better in the long run than any pointless toiletpaper "band aid" you might try with hiding the code.

Comment: Even if your PHP Encryption engine is readable, as long as the keys aren't public, then any encrypted data should be secure

Comment: Indeed, the key here is going to be generated from the random details of files present on the server. I dont want my customers to understand  the PHP code I have written. So, I want it to be pre compiled in to a file which will atleast prevent the users from fiddling with it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that perl can be precompiled.
This might be useful: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=402933